# Issue with illegal string offset

Tags: php

I have this part of code:

```
........

$topic_name = "";

........

function getAllTopics() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $topics = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $topics;
}
```

I am getting error like:

> "PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name' in line..."

The part of code in frontend is:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($topics as $key => $topic): ?>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <th><?php echo $key + 1; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $topic['name']; ?></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I answered your question, was it helpful? If it is then have a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I can see many problems with your existing code and logic.

- No 1. Missing `<? endforeach; ?>` for your starging `foreach` loop
- No 2. Not calling the `getAllTopics()` before using the `$topics`
  variable on your `foreach` loop.
- No 3. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`  Fetch **a** result row as an
  associative array not the all of rows from the table.

I guess you can slightly modify your existing code and do it this way [**Not tested but I hope you got my point**]

```
function getAllTopics() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      $topics[] = $row;  // this will get every single row from table result and push it to $topics array.
    } 
    return $topics;
}


<tbody>
    <?php 
    $topics =  getAllTopics(); // this will get all the topics 
    foreach ($topics as $key => $topic): ?>
     <tr class="odd gradeX">
       <th><?php echo $key + 1; ?></th>
       <th><?php echo $topic['name']; ?></th>
     </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?> // this is the missing endforeach; syntax
</tbody>
```